# Make the first character Uppercase in CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to make the first character ***Uppercase*** in a label in CSS.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<a class="m_title" href="">gorr</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">trro</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">krro</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">yrro</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">gwwr</a>
```

Comment: To specify - the first character and ONLY the first one. Which makes the `text-transform: capitalize;` not enough when having multiple words

Answer (score 904, accepted):

There's a property for that:

```css
a.m_title {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

If your links can contain multiple words and  you only want the first letter of the first word to be uppercase, use `:first-letter` with a different transform instead (although it doesn't really matter). Note that in order for `:first-letter` to work your `a` elements need to be block containers (which can be `display: block`, `display: inline-block`, or any of a variety of other combinations of one or more properties):

```css
a.m_title {
    display: block;
}

a.m_title:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Can this be used with IE8+ ?

Comment: @alanjds: Yes, it works in every version of IE that supports CSS. It's very old technology.

Comment: you might want to use a double semi colon, see http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/

Comment: @Voles: Sure if you don't need to support IE8 and older. Not saying you couldn't use double colons if you wanted to. (For what it's worth, at the time of this answer which was posted 2 and a half years ago, my personal policy *was* to support IE8 by default. Today I no longer do.)

Comment: Note, if the `display: block` requirement (who knows why that is) makes this difficult, `:first-letter` also works with `display: inline-block`.

Comment: It's really unfortunate that `::first-letter` doesn't work on flex box elements.

Comment: @GetFree: Assuming you mean elements with `display: flex`, that is very true. I understand the reasoning behind it, but it can be irritating (if an option at all) to have to put the text in a child element and style that element's `::first-letter` instead.

Comment: @BoltClock, please share with us the rationale behind that decision. Understanding why it's that way will help us feel less irritated about it.

Comment: @GetFree: Well, it's not exactly a decision that was made, just a side effect of the flex container/flex item system. Every child of a flex container is a flex item, including text, which is put in an anonymous flex item. So a flex container can't have a `::first-letter` - only its flex items can. Since you can't target anonymous boxes (hence "anonymous"), the workaround is to put the text in a child element that you *can* target.

Comment: I see. They could've worked around that by defining `::first-letter` to mean the first letter of that first anonymous flex item (if there is one). It seems quite easy to implement.

Comment: @GetFree: The css-pseudo-4 spec seems to [suggest](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#application-in-css) that this could happen in a future spec (as if css-pseudo-4 itself wasn't already one!). You'd need enough interest from both web developers and browser vendors, though.

Comment: why not use 

a.m_title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: @Henry Garcia De Guzman: Because that uppercases everything, not just the first letter (of each word or sentence or whatever).

Comment: Your answer is incorrect: `display: block` is not required, `display: inline-block` can be used instead. Correct your answer.

Comment: Worked for me then it is necessary !important; too

Comment: @c3media importance will only increase rule specificity isn't it? so thats just your particular case where `!important` is required

Answer (score 89):

Note that the `::first-letter` selector does not work with inline elements, so it must be either `block` or `inline-block`, as follows:

```
.m_title {display:inline-block}
.m_title:first-letter {text-transform: uppercase}
```

Comment: In my case the whole text was already in capitals, so I had to add text-transform: lowercase to .m_title and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 65):

Make it lowercase first:

```
.m_title {text-transform: lowercase}
```

Then make it the first letter uppercase:

```
.m_title::first-letter {text-transform: uppercase}
```

"text-transform: capitalize" works for a word; but if you want to use for sentences this solution is perfect.

**Example:**

```css
.m_title {
  display: inline-block; /* Thanks to Fanky (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095642/fanky) */
  
  text-transform: lowercase
}

.m_title::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<a class="m_title" href="">gorr</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">trro trro</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">krro</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">yrro</a>
<a class="m_title" href="">gwwr gwwr gwwr</a>
```

Comment: :first-letter doesn't work with `inline` elements, set to `display:inline-block` if this is your case. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working)

Comment: Yoou got the hack! I have a senario of complete Uppercase and this Backed!

Comment: How is this marked as the answer? `uppercase` makes all the letters capitalized. `capitalize` is the answer.

Comment: "capitalize" capitalizes the first letter of each word. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform#capitalize)

If your text is "gwwr gwwr gwwr", you will get "Gwwr Gwwr Gwwr" when you use "capitalize". But if you want "Gwwr gwwr gwwr", making them all "lowercase" and then making the first-letter "uppercase" is the answer.

Answer (score 61):

[CSS :first-letter Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

or:

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Answer (score 22):

I suggest to use

```css
#selector {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

or

```css
#selector::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

By the way, check this w3schools link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Comment: Good answer, but that's most definitely **not** a link to the w3c documentation.

Comment: Hey, please note: text-transform 'initial' doesn't mean 'capitalize the first letter'. Rather, it means 'revert to the initial, default value for this property'.

Comment: Thanks, I have applied both recommended fixes.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     var asdf = $('.capsf').text();

    $('.capsf').text(asdf.toLowerCase());
     });
     </script>
<div style="text-transform: capitalize;"  class="capsf">sd GJHGJ GJHgjh gh hghhjk ku</div>
```

Comment: it's work me. concept ..paragraph  each word in display first letter caps

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend that you use the following code in CSS:

```
    text-transform:uppercase;
```

Make sure you put it in your class.

Answer (score -6):

Works in React Native too:

```
    textTransform: 'capitalize'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).