# CSS :first-letter not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply CSS styles to some HTML snippets that were generated from a Microsoft Word document.  The HTML that Word generated is fairly atrocious, and includes a lot of inline styles.  It goes something like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <p class=MsoNormal><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span
               style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Title text goes here<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>

            <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:18.0pt;line-height:150%'><span
                style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:150%;font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Content text goes here.<o:p></o:p></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and very simply, I would like to style the first letter of the title section.  It just needs to be larger and in a different font.  To do this I am trying to use the `:first-letter` selector, with something kind of like:

```
p b span:first-letter {
    font-size: 500px !important;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  Here's a fiddle demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KvGr2/

Any ideas what is wrong/how to get the first letter of the title section styled correctly?  I can make minor changes to the markup (like adding a wrapper div around things), though not without some difficulty.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

`::first-letter` does not work on **inline** elements such as a `span`. `::first-letter` works on **block** elements such as a paragraph, table caption, table cell, list item, or those with their `display` property set to `inline-block`.

Therefore it's better to apply `::first-letter` to a `p` instead of a `span`.

```
p::first-letter {font-size: 500px;}
```

or if you want a `::first-letter` selector in a `span` then write it like this:

```
p b span::first-letter {font-size: 500px !important;}
span {display:block}
```

MDN [provides the rationale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) for this non-obvious behaviour:

> The `::first-letter` CSS pseudo-element selects the first letter of the first line of a block, if it is not preceded by any other content (such as images or inline tables) on its line.
>
> ...
>
> A first line has only meaning in a block-container box, therefore the `::first-letter` pseudo-element has only an effect on elements with a `display` value of `block`, `inline-block`, `table-cell`, `list-item` or `table-caption`. In all other cases, `::first-letter` has no effect.

**Another odd case**(apart from not working on inline items) is if you use `:before` the `:first-letter` will apply to the before not the actual first letter see [codepen](https://codepen.io/T04435/pen/poyjyMb)

### Examples

- http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/KvGr2/9/
- http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/css/first-letter-inline-block/

### References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter

Comment: Thanks for this. One odd thing I have noticed - the % sign gets resized too? http://jsfiddle.net/iamkeir/KvGr2/76/

Comment: Funny enough it also works fine for cases where the parent item is a flex-box. Apparently changing the children to flex-items has the same result as explicitly setting those to something else then "inline". See example [here in a fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/g9j82uoq/1/)

Comment: It seems the `:first-letter` selector doesn't work for elements with `display: -webkit-box;` either.

Answer (score 21):

You can get the intended behavior by setting the span's display property to inline-block:

```css
.heading span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.heading span:first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <span>An</span>
  <span>Interesting</span>
  <span>Heading</span>
</div>
```

Comment: how to do it if my text start with symbols. <div>! Session Expired</div>

Comment: It'll apply to the symbol and to the first letter, unless there's a space in between. (This is so that e.g. "Quotations" and —Citations with leading punctuation treat first-letter in a rational way, since the most common use is drop caps.)

Answer (score 9):

This is because `:first-letter` only operates on block / inline-block elements. `SPAN` is an inline element.

Taken from http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter:

> The :first-letter pseudo-element is mainly used for creating common
>   typographical effects like drop caps. This pseudo-element represents
>   the first character of the first formatted line of text in a
>   block-level element, an inline block, a table caption, a table cell,
>   or a list item.