# CSS first-letter Selector in a link

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm currently getting headaches from this darn pseudo-element called `:first-letter`. It seems to be so helpful, but ultimately does not work the way I expected.

Here's an example on jsfiddle, how I tried and how it should look like:

FIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4DnKu/)

As you can see, `:first-letter` does nothing. I expected it to overwrite the normal link settings and also the `:hover` selector.

What could've possibly gone wrong? Any other idea how to achieve this **only with CSS**?

Comment: Reading here might be of use http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter it looks to be not as far reaching as you would expect. From my tests I could only get this selector to work with `p` tags, at least so far.

Comment: I haven't researched, but testing that fiddle says- a) `»` does not count as a letter, and b) `:first-letter` does not work on `<a>` tags. I got it working as a p tag, with a letter hidden before the M: http://jsfiddle.net/4DnKu/2/

Comment: can you post the images your desired result image.........

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working/7631782#7631782

Comment: @sandeep: That must be the reason! Links are inline on default - and in my case I will need an inline-element.

Comment: @Shailender Arora: The second link is what I want, but with the markup of the first link (no span).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting your "»" in the HTML you could put it in the CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/4DnKu/4/

```
a.one:before {
    content: "»";
    color:#0F0;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
}
```

IMHO it shouldn't be in the HTML either way, as it actually is only decoration.

Pseudo elements are supported by all major browsers, only one you'll have problems with is IE<8. There you could use CSS expressions as a workaround (handle with care!):

```
a.one {
    *zoom: expression( (new Function('elem', '\
        if(elem.before)\
            return;\
        elem.innerHTML = "<span class=ie7-before>»</span>" + elem.innerHTML;\
        elem.before = true;\
        elem.style.zoom = "1";\
    '))(this) );
}

a.one > .ie7-before,
a.one:before {
    content: "»";
    color:#0F0;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
}
```

This uses quite a few hacks, so I would not recommend using it unless you understand what is going on there.

Comment: You're right, I don't like the way the arrow is written in the HTML, generating it with CSS would be the best way. Your solution is almost perfect - almost.. in my case it is also needed that the arrow has no underline anymore. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: So basically you added inline-block (and some margin for new positioning), that'S awesome, I would've never found out about that. Thanks!!