# p:first child doesn't work if a img tag is immediately after the p tag?

Tags: html, css, image

Hy there,
can't make it to work i have something like this

```
    .body-post p:first-child:first-letter
    {
    font-size:240%;
    }
```

and here the html:

```
    <div class="body-post">
    <p><img src="http://#" align="left" style="margin-right:5px;"/>
    some text</p></div>
```

So if theres no picture the first letter works. Is there a way to skip the img tag. I cant edit the source code because im doing some template for a blogger domain. nothing serious, its just so confusing. first letter should select the letter not the image.

Comment: I would just pull the `<img>` outside of the `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working) I found out that first-letter can only be used on block elements (which you were doing).

In this solution I increased the selectivity of the text by wrapping it in a span and put in the proper styling to make the span an inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/52Vjm/1/

```
<div>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"/>
        <span>Kittens are great</span>
    </p>
</div>

span:first-letter { font-size:2em; }
span { display:inline-block; }
img { margin-right:5px; }
```

Comment: Why would you nest the text in a span? This is bad schematically for SEO!

Comment: O really!? Care to expand on that with some proofs?

Answer (score 1):

Put the image out side of the P tag and use the following. The image will still allow the P to wrap as that is what floating an element does.

```
 .body-post > p:first-child:first-letter {
    font-size:240%;
 }

  <div class="body-post">
    <img src="http://#" align="left" style="margin-right:5px;"/>
    <p>some text</p>
 </div>
```

//Side note, try to avoid using inline styles when possible. It can interfere with JS and media queries/