# Get :first-letter to ignore image?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I’m trying to get :first-letter working when there is other elements there, is it possible?

I’ve created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4UH/) to illustrate.

```
<h3 class="title"> 
 <img  src="/imgs/small-logo.png" width="31" height="30" />
 Test
 </h3>
 <h3 class="title"> 
 Test
 </h3>
```

Anyway using :first-of-type or something, but i cannot get it to ignore the img.

The only other way was to wrap the letter in a span and style, but i’m not keen on separating as when the screen collapses so does the rest of the word below..

Comment: Thanks guys, they work along with [this example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840198/pfirst-child-doesnt-work-if-a-img-tag-is-immediately-after-the-p-tag

Comment: Apply the logo via h3.title { background-image et al.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to adapt your mark-up you could wrap your *whole* string of text within a span.

HTML:

```
<h3 class="title"> 
     <img  src="/imgs/small-logo.png" width="31" height="30" />
     <span>Test</span>
 </h3>

<h3 class="title"> 
    <span>Test</span>
</h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3.title {
    color: #004265;
}
h3.title span {
    display: inline-block;
}
h3.title span:first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

`:first-letter` only works on block level elements, hence setting the span to `inline-block`.

Here is the working code - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4UH/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You could try changing the position of the image so it comes after the text and then use `float: left` on the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/mp4UH/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter)

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element selects the first letter of the
>   first line of a block, if it is not preceded by any other content
>   (such as images or inline tables) on its line.

The only potential solution I can think of is to float the image so it escapes this rule, e.g.

```
h3.title img{
    float:left;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AF2eS/)

Comment: If it's a logo then it's styling and using a pseudo-element would be preferable to an actual image. Or even just adding padding and using the logo as bg image on the heading element.