# Firefox not applying styles to "first-child:first-letter"

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a certain style to the first letter in my header, which is made up of text. My webpage is here: http://smarterinfive.com

It works well in Chrome, but not at all in FF. Here are properties I already tried applying my styles to, with no avail (in FF):

```
header[role="banner"] .branding:first-letter {
background: #000;
}

.branding:first-child:first-letter {
background: #000;
 }

.branding h1 a:first-child:first-letter {
background: #000;
}
```

It seems that anything with `first-letter` or `first-child:first-letter` isn't working, but everything with `first-child` **only** IS.

I also tried:

1. Adding `!important` at the end of these.
2. Viewing it in the developer tools, which didn't show the property at all.

Comment: Where on that page are those styles?  I'm not finding them...

Comment: I don’t see a difference between renderings on Chrome and on Firefox for the main heading, except that it is left-aligned on Chrome, centered on Firefox. The question should specify which CSS code is used on the demo page and what is the expected effect.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky - I'm not applying these styles yet because as per my question, they are not being applied consistently on different browsers.

@JukkaK.Korpela - The header is centered in Firefox?! it shouldn't be. and regarding specifying which CSS code is used: 1. I'm not sure different CSS is being used 2. it doesn't matter since I've tried this with firebug too 3. all other changes that I've made, that don't have `first-letter` in them, have been applied consistently until now.

Comment: @Darwin229 well, its hard to tell you what's going wrong without seeing the actual page.  In my testing, the styles above work fine.  So can you link to a page that shows the problem for you?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky - Ok, I have added a 0.05em padding to the property `.branding h1:first-letter` and it's showing up in Chrome, but in FF. It's intentionally small so visitors coming to the site won't notice it. But you can see it in Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: I have now removed the padding demo since changes I will actually get help are slim. If anyone still wants to pick this up and help, that'll be great.

Comment: @Darwin229 Um...  You put it up over the weekend, when I'm obviously less likely to look at work stuff.  Mind putting it back so I can actually take a look?

Answer (score 2):

The problem for `.branding h1 a:first-child:first-letter` is that `first-letter` can only be applied to block elements, not inline elements like `a`. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working)

I also don't understand why the others aren't working...

But why do you need to even use `first-child`?

You can get the same effect and solve the problem with this:

```
.branding h1:first-letter {
  background: black;
}
```

It's actually more simple.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AvThr/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. It seems that anything with `first-letter` or `first-child:first-letter` isn't working, but everything with `first-child` **only** IS.

Comment: @Darwin229: What version of FF are you on? I am running 19.0.2 on a Win7 machine and bookcasey's Demo is changing for me. [My own demo I set up to test](http://jsfiddle.net/zb9va/) is also working for me, which has the combined selector `h1:first-child:first-letter`.

Comment: @Darwin229: it would seem version really should not matter since [its been supported by FF since 1.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::first-letter).

Comment: Yep, I still can't figure how to sort this out :/