# Add background to first letter of a row of text. How?

Tags: html, css

Please look at the attached image, below:

[image: What I want to achieve]

This, I made up easily in Photoshop and is for the corporate identity on papers and such. However: I now need to create that for an email signature. Though.. I don't have a clue how to achieve the effect of having a square/rectangular background to the - well let's say - first letter of the sentence.

Since It should not cut off the text to the next row, I can't use a `<p>` tag.

I hope someone could help me! However, it's for an E-mail signature and all CSS must be inline. edit: And besides that: You can't use DIV's either.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:first-letter`

```
div:first-letter {
    padding: 0 3px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVcSR/)

Or a [**better one**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVcSR/1/)

```
div:first-letter {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: #174D95;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

> Note: You can replace `div` with a `p` element too, but `:first-letter` will not work on [inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working).

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVcSR/3/) (Using `p` tag)

---

As you wanted to do this with a `span` tag, you need to define it as `inline-block;` to make the `:first-letter` work.

Doing this with a `span` tag - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVcSR/4/)

```
span:first-letter {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: #174D95;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

span {
   display:block
}
```

Comment: I should have stated in my OP that the use of DIV's isn't supported in E-mail signatures.. 

Got an alternative?

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer You can use `p` or any other element there

Comment: and since it's inline..  I just use the code of:

`<p:firstline style="padding:2px, 5px; etc."> ... </p>` I guess?

And while writing and trying, I could also use spans..

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I added a demo with a span tag

Comment: As said: CSS Should be inline. However, the CSS you've written down here made me got it working, as I made it inline myself. Thanks so very much!

Correction: made in inline, but instead of using `:first-letter`, I set the closing `</span>` after the first letter. Thanks!

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Yea even that will work as well, also it won't break the layout as there's isn't any rendering difference between inline and inline block unless and until you use paddings or margins, and you welcome :)