# CSS - First-letter selection not working with ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

My CSS :first-letter selector works with all `p` elements, but with a `span` that has an id `#fletter` it won't work...

---

```
#fletter span:first-letter {
    font-weight: 600;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

---

```
<span id="fletter">
```

---

The selector works fine with my `p` elements, though.

---

```
p:first-letter {
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

---

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `:first-letter` can only be used on block level elements.

One solution could be to display the span as a block level element:

```
#fletter span {
   display:block;
}

#fletter span:first-letter {
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 25px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdkJs/1/)

Answer (score 7):

`:first-letter` does not work on **inline** elements such as a `span`. 
others inline elements are:

> b, big, i, small, tt
>   abbr, acronym, cite, code, dfn, em, kbd, strong, samp, var
>   a, bdo, br, img, map, object, q, script, span, sub, sup
>   button, input, label, select, textarea

`:first-letter` works on **block** elements such as a paragraph, table caption, table cell, list item, or those with the `inline-block` property applied.

if you want a `:first-letter` selector in a `span` then write it like this:

```
p span:first-letter {font-size: 500px !important;}
span {display:block}

<p>
 <span>text here</span>
</p>
```

Comment: With that HTML, you can write `p:first-letter {..}` and you don't have to change the span at all.

Answer (score 3):

As written, you're targeting a `span` inside of something with the id `fletter`.  You either need to do

```
#fletter:first-letter {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
}
```

or, if you know this will always be a `span`:

```
span#fletter:first-letter {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you need to use a `span` as opposed to a `p`, `div`, heading, etc., you will also need to include `display: block` in the style for `:first-letter` to work.  Whether you use my answer or @dsg 's, depends on whether the span you want to affect is inside another span with ID `fletter` or the span you want to affect has ID `fletter`

Answer (score 3):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3afirst-letter), the `first-letter` property applies to block elements.

So, not spans. Sorry. You may have to create an inner span containing the first letter, maybe with Javascript or something. Or, if it's possible, give the span `display:inline-block`.

Comment: To be very precise, `:first-letter` is a pseudo-element, and it can be applied to not just "block elements", but *block container* elements. That is why `display: inline-block` works - even though an inline block itself flows inline like all other inlines, its *contents* participate in a block formatting context that's generated by it.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but you are lacking the requires 2 colons.
This works perfectly fine for me in Chrome etc:

```
#<idname>::first-letter{
    color: green;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

:first-letter only works on block elements, and span is, by default, inline.  You can either set the span to be a block element (display:block) or use a div instead (divs are block by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
#fletter:first-letter {
font-size: 100px;
color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

Try this one. In my case it is working fine