# How to apply :first-letter pseudo-element for div with display:flex?

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-element

:first-letter pseudo-element isn't working for div with display: flex property. but it works for block and inline-block elements.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

div:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div>flex</div>
<div style="display: block">block</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">inline-block</div>
```

Comment: You can, however, assign the style to the first child of the flex container. `div::first-letter, div > :first-child::first-letter {..}` Provided, of course, that the div does have child elements.

Comment: For more info you can refer this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working"