# ::first-letter on <sub> and <sup>

Tags: javascript, html, css

It looks like `<sub>` and `<sup>` are not supporting the `::first-letter` *CSS pseudo-element*. Any idea how to solve it?

```css
p:first-letter,
sub:first-letter,
sup:first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p>
<p>This text contains <sup>superscript</sup> text.</p>
```

##### Update

As @temani-afif pointed out, this was answered on [html - CSS :first-letter not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working), just I wasn't able to find it focusing specifically on `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags, which are not mentioned in that topic.

Answer (score 2):

> The `::first-letter` CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not preceded by other content.
> -- [::first-letter - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

The `<sub>` and `<sup>`elements are not *block-level elements* by default, but using the CSS `display` Property with the `inline-block` value
can change this.

```css
p:first-letter,
sub:first-letter,
sup:first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
sub,
sup {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p>
<p>This text contains <sup>superscript</sup> text.</p>
```