# automated HTML Page Capitalization

Tags: html, capitalization

Is there a method to automatically capitalize an HTML page instead of performing the task manually ?
For example, transforming **"HOW Does That SOund?"** into **"How does that sound?"**

Do you believe that Prettier is incapable of handling that for me?

Answer (score 2):

Live example with pure HTML & CSS using `text-transform`:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

span::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span>HOW Does That SOund?</span>
```

Explanation:

> `<span>` is inline element
>
> `::first-letter` only works with `block` or `inline-block` elements

#### Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter
- [CSS :first-letter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with JavaScript, you could write a script to manipulate the text content programmatically. Here's a simple example using JavaScript:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
      element.textContent = element.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<div id="myElement">HOW Does That SOund?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by integrating specific JavaScript code. You can implement this code in any of your projects, and it will automatically format everything like magic.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      capitalizeSentences(document.body);
    });

    function capitalizeSentences(element) {
      if (element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        var text = element.nodeValue.trim();

        if (text !== '') {
          // Capitalize the first letter of the first word
          element.nodeValue = capitalizeFirstLetter(text);
        }
      } else {
        element.childNodes.forEach(function(childNode) {
          capitalizeSentences(childNode);
        });
      }
    }

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(text) {
      var sentences = text.split('. ');

      sentences = sentences.map(function(sentence) {
        if (sentence.length > 0) {
          return sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sentence.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        }
        return sentence;
      });

      return sentences.join('. ');
    }
```