# How to Capitalize first letter only using CSS in each case

Tags: css, cpu-word, capitalization

I want to Capitalize first letter only and **other should be small** using CSS

String is:

```
SOMETHING BETTER 
sOMETHING bETTER
Something better
```

but the result should be

```
Something Better
```

Is this possible using CSS? To Capitalize first letter I am using

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

But not able to capitalize in each case.
"I want to use CSS because in my application it has written every where hard coded but a class has been called everywhere."

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone. Even trying to cascade a `text-transform: lowercase` into a `text-transform: capitalize` won't work. If you want to use javascript, here's a link to an answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript

Comment: In PHP - `ucwords("UPPERCASE WORD HERE");`, and the result : `Uppercase Word Here"` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php You can't do it using just CSS, because you can't do `lowercase` and then `capitalize`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [make the first character uppercase in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css)

Comment: @yoeriboven: I don't think it's the same.

Answer (score 39):

you should be able to use the `:first-letter` pseudo element:

```
.fl {
 display: inline-block;
}

.fl:first-letter {
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

<p>
 <span class="fl">something</span> <span class="fl">better</span>
</p>
```

yields:

Something Better

Comment: This is correct, but means each word needs to be wrapped in a `span`, which is ugly

Comment: Added some [javascript magic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17451072/561731) ^_^ @mzmm56

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible with CSS alone but you can do it with Javascript or PHP for example.

In **PHP**

```
ucwords()
```

And in **Javascript**

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Extracted from
[Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You can try a combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17450755/561731) and some javascript (using jQuery)

HTML:

```
<div class='capitalize'>
    SOMETHING BETTER 
    SOMETHING BETTER 
    SOMETHING BETTER 
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.capitalize').each(function(){
    var text = this.innerText;
    var words = text.split(" ");
    var spans = [];
    var _this = $(this);
    this.innerHTML = "";
    words.forEach(function(word, index){
        _this.append($('<span>', {text: word}));
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.capitalize {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.capitalize span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em  
}

.capitalize span:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ZHhqj/

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you just use the :first-letter pseudo element in css?

```
h2:first-letter{
text-transform: uppercase;

}

h2{

*your general code for h2 goes here;*

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, CSS is no help here. Welcome to the world of JavaScript, where anything is possible.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("each-word")
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\\b/gim, "<span class='first-letter'>$1</span>$2")
  }
}



  .first-letter {
    color: red;
  }



<p class="each-word">First letter of every word is now red!</p>
```

Comment: Wrong, it's completely possible in CSS. Javascript is overkill.