# make first character of each word capital in input

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can i automatically make first character of the word in an input area
Currently my code is

```
Name:<input type='text' name='name' class='name' placeholder='Enter your name here'/>
```

Comment: So you want it to look different, or actually become different? CSS cannot do the latter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [make the first character uppercase in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SDEze/)

```
Name:<input type='text' name='name' class='name' style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder='Enter your name here'/>
```

or add `text-transform: capitalize;` in your `name` in css.

Comment: It works only in the sense that the initial letters are *displayed* to the user in uppercase. The actual data in the DOM (as accessible to JavaScript code) and as submitted in form data will still be as the user entered it.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela -I will request you to edit my answer with appropriate `javascript` code to do the same.

Comment: It would be inappropriate to edit someone else’s answer to something completely different. Since the OP has accepted this answer, it seems that he actually wanted the text look different from what it actually is as form data, even though that sounds odd.

Comment: It also capitalizes the placeholder text—in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: It still accepts capital letters in between if user entered within a word, like `dZone`

Answer (score 7):

The problem with using CSS (text-transform: capitalize) is that when the form gets submitted, the name will be submitted with a lowercase name.

The CSS works well for cosmetics but not for functionality.

You can use jQuery to force capitalization functionality in your input boxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.name').keyup(function(event) {
        var textBox = event.target;
        var start = textBox.selectionStart;
        var end = textBox.selectionEnd;
        textBox.value = textBox.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + textBox.value.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        textBox.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    });
});
</script>
```

Put this code between the `<head> </head>` on the page where your form is located.

Above jQuery will also force ALL CAPS to Capitalize.

Check out the Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cgaybba/6rps8hfo/

Answer (score 3):

I think it should also be mentioned that if the form is on mobile, you can just use the `autocapitalize` attribute. [see here for documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type='text' name='name' class='name' placeholder='Enter your name here'/>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
<style>
 .name 
{
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.contact_person_name').keyup(function(event) {
    var textBox = event.target;
    var start = textBox.selectionStart;
    var end = textBox.selectionEnd;
    
    // Capitalize the first letter of each word after a space
    textBox.value = textBox.value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function(match) {
      return match.toUpperCase();
    });
    
    textBox.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="contact_person_name" id="contact_person_name" name="contact_person_name">
```

Comment: This code is working perfact for me because i want that it will take capital text after sapace

Answer (score 0):

Update you css

```
.name { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The good side of using JS is that when the user submits the form, it retains the capitalized input values, but using css when the form is submitted, it looses the capitalized values (for frontend only).

Note for CSS: make sure you don't have any overriding styles else use !important.

//For CSS

```
input { text-transform: capitalize }
```

//For JS

```
$('.your-input').on('change keydown paste', function(e) {
    if (this.value.length = 1) {}
    var $this_val = $(this).val();
    this_val = $this_val.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(char) {
    return char.toUpperCase();
    });
    $(this).val(this_val);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just include →  style="text-transform:capitalize;" inside your input tag.

Comment: Same solution as other answers.