# Change first letter uppercase and others lowercase using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change all the text inside an li like teh first letter to Uppercase and the others are in lower like as follows.
But it is not working,Why?

```css
ul li{
      display: inline-table;
      text-transform: lowercase;
}
ul li:first-letter{
     text-transform: uppercase !important; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEsTt1</li>
  <li>TeSt2</li>
  <li>TesT3</li>
  <li>TEsT4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `text-transform: capitalize;` use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make the first character uppercase in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css)

Comment: This should solve your Problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css

Comment: display: inline-table; I can't change this

Comment: @MikeLambert my text may be like "TEsTt1"

Comment: @Sumitpatel my text may be like "TEsTt1"

Answer (score 5):

Convert the innerText to lowercase and use the text-transform capitalize to get Pascal casing

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul>li')
.forEach(function(node){
  node.innerText = node.innerText.toLowerCase();
})
```

```css
ul li{
      display: inline-table;
      text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>tEst1</li>
  <li>teSt2</li>
  <li>TesT3</li>
  <li>tESt4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update Css**

```
ul li::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase; 

}
ul li
{
  text-transform: lowercase;   
}
```

Live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mh5w4t5w/)

Comment: use `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul>li')
.forEach(function(node){
  node.innerText = node.innerText.toLowerCase();
})
```

```css
ul li{
      display: inline-table;
      text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>tEst1</li>
  <li>teSt2</li>
  <li>TesT3</li>
  <li>tESt4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you might need to use javascript to get it done for such cases

Comment: That's true, haven't thought of that

Answer (score 0):

```
ul>li{
text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Use above code