# How to make first letter capital using css

Tags: css

I wand to make my first letter in `<span>` in capital. But when i use `:before` in the `span` capitalize is not working.

```
span { display:inline-block; color:#66a400; }
span:first-letter { text-transform:capitalize; }
span:before { content:"-"; padding:0 2px; }

<span>my first word</span>
```

I need out put like below

```
- My first word
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make the first character uppercase in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css)

Comment: @albert It's not a dup, the OP problem is with the before pseudo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:after` instead of `:before` and float it to the left:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #66a400;
}
span:first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
span:after {
  content: "-";
  padding: 0 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span>my first word</span>
```

Comment: Working with float is a bit risky. Dont you need to clear it than ?

Comment: @DomeTune It's not risky at all. And in this case it's not necessary to clear it even.

Comment: @DomeTune If floated :pseudo was taller *and* span still `inline` than yes you'd need to clear(fix) some element. [Here's a case](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/EZMmEB). But here no because span is `inline-block` and even if it wasn't that :pseudo is exactly as tall as surrounding text :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem due to the `span:before` selector, see below.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

> The first letter of an element is not necessarily trivial to identify:
>
> ...
>
> Finally, a combination of the ::before pseudo-element and the content property may inject some text at the beginning of the element.
>   In that case, ::first-letter will match the first letter of this
>   generated content.

If you want the "-" before the content with first letter capitalized, you can do as follows, changing your structure and css

CSS

```
span { display:inline-block; color:#66a400; }
span#before::before { content:"- "; padding:0 2px; }
span#content { text-transform:capitalize; }
```

HTML

```
<span id="before"></span><span id="content">my first word</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
span { display:inline-block; color:#66a400; }
```

span:before { content:"-"; padding:0 2px; }
span { text-transform:capitalize; }

```
<p><span>my</span> first word</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
span::first-letter { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: So what, it won't work for the same reason as why original OP's attempt doesn't work.