# uppercase first letter of month fullcalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

Can anyone help me uppercase the first letter of the month in fullcalendar? When I write the fullcalendar, I found that the in English, for example August, the display of month in title is correctly "August" or "Aug.". But in Spanish the first letter of the month is not capitalized. For example, "Agosto" and "Ago." is "agosto" and "ago.".

Is there any way to correct this using css or the only way is to change the `locale_all.js` file?

[image: situation for the moment AgendaWeek view]
[image: situation for the moment month view]

Comment: CSS : `text-transform: capitalize;` ?

Comment: @l2aelba: emm, i have already tried this one. With this css, i got AGOSTO 2017, but what my client need is Agosto 2017 -0-, this is the probleme

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal: Thank you for the resource. But i have already tried this one-0-, that doesn't work for me although i don't know why.

Comment: `capitalize` should only transforms the first character of each word to uppercase. @l2aelba 's solution should work. You can check and try [all CSS text-transform properties here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp).

Comment: @brian17han: thank you, i'll check it

Comment: I don't know Spanish culture but perhaps, if that's the way it's formatted in the Spanish locale file, it's because that's the way Spanish speakers would expect it to appear? Just a thought, worth checking.

Comment: @I2aelba: emm,sry, today i retried your response and it works now for me =-=, but there is another one who give an answer as yours, can you give your answer as answer and i can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using CSS, you can easily capitalize the first alphabet of the title (month).

please use this `.fc-toolbar { text-transform: capitalize; }`

or you can also check the link [First capital spanish letter](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/LjBVLZ)

Comment: Thank you, this works, but there is already another one who gives the same answer so i can't give you a check. Sorry

Comment: It doesn't matter, I was just helping you out because you were struggling with the issue and nobody said that you have to place this `text-tranform: capitalize` on the `.fc-toolbar` class which is a fullcalendar class