# Capitalize only 1st letter instead of all the words

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to capitalize only 1st letter.
for Example: `FIRST NAME` converted to `First name`

Using below code :

```
 1. textTransform: 'capitalize', // Result is  First Name
 2. I tried to use import startCase from 'lodash.startcase';
          and used startCase('FIRST NAME') // Result is  First Name
```

Please let me know if there is any way to implement this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't see any code below the line *"below code:"*...

Answer (score 2):

[Capitalize with css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577380/13777749)

[Capitalize with JavaScript](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-uppercase-first-letter-javascript/)

Comment: capitalize or lower case will make all the First character capital after space

Comment: @SwetaDodiya Did you try the second option? p:first-letter {text-transform: uppercase}