# Capitalize first letter of a string using Angular (input box)

Tags: angular14

Capitalize first letter of a string using Angular for input boxes

input boxes first letter should automatically turn when enter a letter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the first character Uppercase in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform):

```css
input {text-transform: capitalize;}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you and i will use this in the Scss/Css