# I am doing a problem that I have to capitalize the first letter of each word in a provided string

Tags: javascript, loops

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  const words = str.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
  }
  words.join(" ");

  return words
}
console.log(generateHashtag("i am a good coder"))
```

This is the code I have come up with but after iterating the string, the output is an array with the first words capitalized. How do I join up the words from the array to form back the sentence without the spaces?

Comment: Try: `words.join("")`

Comment: Did you mean to return the result of `.join()` rather than returning `words`?

Comment: the output is an array still [ 'I', 'Am', 'A', 'Good', 'Coder' ] and the desired output is IAmAGoodCoder.

Comment: BTW if this is for a web page, here's a way to do this with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css

Comment: CSS is generally a safer way to solve problems, as it is generally easier to maintain and never results in a programming error.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a new `string`. Return that value directly instead of calling it on `words` without assignment.

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  const words = str.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
  }

  return words.join(" ");
}

console.log(generateHashtag("i am a good coder"));
```

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> The `join()` method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

Answer (score 1):

words.join() creates a new value, it doesn't update the words value.

Try this:

```
function generateHashtag(str) {
  const words = str.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
  }

  return words.join(' ')
}
console.log(generateHashtag("i am a good coder"))
```

Here we return words.join(' ')